# .populate() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been working on this for hours and can't find a solution.

I am making a school directory using a

Student Model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");


var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        courses: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref:  "Course"
            }
        ]
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);
```

and a Course Model...

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
var courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema (
    {
        name: String,
        student: [
            {
                id: 
                {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: "Student"
                },
                name: String
            }
        ]
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);
```

When I run .populate on a found student... it does not populate the Course values within the Student...

```
app.get("/students/:id", function(req, res){
    Student.findById(req.params.id).populate("courses").exec(function(err, foundStudent){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(foundStudent);
            res.render("students/show", {student: foundStudent});
        }
    });
});
```

The console.log(foundStudent) will display...

```
{ _id: 597e7a49c945ee13529d0871,
  name: 'Collin DeSoto',
  __v: 1,
  courses: [ { _id: 597e7a4dc945ee13529d0872 } ] }
```

AFTER the populate.. any ideas?

Comment: It's likely that your actual documents do not in fact match the schema you have implemented. In fact `courses: [ { _id: 597e7a4dc945ee13529d0872 } ]` suggests that it does not since it should be `courses: [ 597e7a4dc945ee13529d0872 ]` indicating a plain array of `ObjectId`, which is what the schema says.

Comment: Sorry, by documents are you referring to my routes or the models themselves?

Comment: Document. As shown in your `console.log()` output above. It **does not match** the defined schema.

Comment: Well I am not really sure where to start here.

Comment: I already told you what to do. Fix your data. Your data contains an "array of objects" with an `_id` property like this: `courses: [ { _id: 597e7a4dc945ee13529d0872 } ]`. You need to make it an "array of `ObjectId`" as defined in your schema like this: `courses: [ 597e7a4dc945ee13529d0872 ]`. Note there is **no** `_id` field, and that matches the schema definition and is the typical pattern. Your data does not match what you have defined. Either 1. Fix the data to match the schema. 2. Fix the Schema to match the data.

Comment: Well I have the type set to mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId so I don't know why that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Is this better? `var mongoose = require("mongoose");


var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        courses: [
            {
                id:
                {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref:  "Course"
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    
module.exports = mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);`?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
User.find(match, function (err, users) {
 var opts = [{ path: 'company', match: { x: 1 }, select: 'name' }]

  var promise = User.populate(users, opts);
  promise.then(console.log).end();
})
```

and prefar this link [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate)